# Redux state updated but props still received as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following component which calls a Factory to create both heroes and cells, and once the array is full, pass it to the state variables with the same name.

**Field.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import _ from "lodash";

import Factory from './../Factory/Factory';
import { addHero, addCell } from './../../store/actions/actionsCreator';

class Field extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        let heros = [],
            cells = [];

        //id=0 will throw a error, always start with 1
        for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            heros.push(this.callFactory('hero', i));
        }
        this.props.addHero(heros);

        for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            for (let j = 1; j < 12; j++) {
                let cell = this.callFactory('cell', j, i);
                cells.push(cell);
            }
        }
        this.props.addCell(cells);

        this.movePerson(1, {x: 2, y: 1});
    }


    callFactory(type, id, number){
        return Factory.build(type, id, number)
    }


    render() {
        const {heros,cells} = this.props;

        if(heros === undefined) return null;

        // console.log(this.props);

        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {cells[0]}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {heros[0]}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        heros: state.heros,
        cells: state.cells
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addHero(hero) {
            dispatch(addHero(hero));
        },
        addCell(cell) {
            dispatch(addCell(cell));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Field);
```

There is my reducer file:

**index.js (reducer file)**

```
import {createStore } from 'redux'

const initialState = {
    heros: [],
    cells: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_HERO':
            return {
                ...state,
                heros: [...state.heros, action.hero]
            }

        case 'ADD_CELL':
            return {
                ...state,
                cells: [...state.cells, action.cell]
            }

        default:
            return {
                ...state
            }
    }

}

export default createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

The file with all my actions:

**actionCreator.js**

```
const addHero = hero => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_HERO',
        hero
    }
}

const addCell = cell => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_CELL',
        cell
    }
}


export {  addHero, addCell };
```

And my app entry point:

**index.js**

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './styles/index.css';

import Field from './components/Field/Field';
import store from './store/index';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store= {store}>
        <Field/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

The key problem here is when I try to log my props value at any point it will be logged as undefined, but if I log the props inside render it will be called 2 times, the first one as undefined and the second one with the updated state.
Is there any way to handle this problem so I can use the  props values outside render?

Comment: Your logic looks sound.  You first render the component with no heros or cells, after that render you call componentDidMount and load heros, and after the state is updated you render again and heros is defined.  Props can be used outside render once the state has been updated, you can log them in componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: i just noticed you are using componentWillMount, I guess you are thinking that those state changes will execute before the render.  That is not the case, you want to be doing that type of logic in componentDidMount which runs after the initial render: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Hi @brub thanks for the aclaration, Im just starting with react/redux so as you well pointed my logic is very bad in this area. Aside from doing all this stuff inside ComponentDidMount instead of WillMount would you pass the array as props to field? so then you can acces it in willMount

Comment: If you want the array accessible in componentWillMount, you need to pass the populated array to the component as a prop, which means you would simply move the loading logic to the parent component.   Is the problem that you don't like the initial render where you return null because heros is undefined?  If that is the case you would move the loading logic to the parent component.

Comment: yes I will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these two react  component cycle. 
First one is componentDidMount(). You should this method instead of componentWillMount(). 
Second one is componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps). With the help of this method, you can see the changes nextProps and currently prop you have.

Comment: Hi @yasinv thanks for the help, will try to change all the code to work this way!

Answer (score 0):

As @brub and @yasinv pointed, the main problem was calling all the logic inside ComponentWillMount and not ComponentDidMount.
If someone is in the same spot, I decided to pass this information (heros and cells) as props to my Field component, and then trigger ComponentDidMount to treat this data.